# Is it possible to make Google Sheets import range static after importing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I want to copy data from another Sheet (n=3000+) and able to modify, write and delete it. But Sheet will always override from the original imported data, so whatever I tried to overwrite or delete will be restored back to the original form. So is there a way to keep all the imported data static?

```
=IMPORTRANGE("KEYA","SHEET1!A2:A")
```

So if sheet A is the data being imported, sheet B should be able to freely modified without changing back to sheet A's data.

Comment: For example, how about directly putting the values to the sheet using Google Apps Script? By this, the values can be statically put. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying, the sheet that is imported in is from another account, how would I put the values in using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About ``the sheet that is imported in is from another account``, I cannot understand the situation. Can I ask you about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you to copy the values from one sheet to another with the `getRange()`, `getValues()` and `setValues()` methods which you can find in the Apps Script Reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet

You could do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {  
var OriginalRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_of_your_desired_spreadsheet').getSheetByName('name_of_the_original_sheet').getRange("A2:A");
var DestinationRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_of_your_desired_spreadsheet').getSheetByName('name_of_the_destination_sheet').getRange("A2:A");
DestinationRange.setValues(OriginalRange.getValues());
}
```

This will copy the values from one sheet to another statically, when you run the script manually.

Comment: Would this also work if the spreadsheet is from another person's account (assuming I have the permission to view that spreadsheet)?

Comment: If you have the permission to open the file, you can also open it from Apps Script by its ID.